# Playing with Graphics in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, adobe

I was just going through one code used to draw one chart. This code is written in the `updateDisplayList` function of the `ItemRenderer` of `ColumnChart`. I am not good at the graphics part of Flex. Can anybody please explain me what this code is doing? I can see the final output, but am not sure how is this achieved.

```
var rc:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, width , height);
var g:Graphics = graphics;

g.clear();        
g.moveTo(rc.left,rc.top);
g.beginFill(fill);
g.lineTo(rc.right,rc.top);
g.lineTo(rc.right,rc.bottom);
g.lineTo(rc.left,rc.bottom);
g.lineTo(rc.left,rc.top);
g.endFill();
```

Regards, PK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It basically draws a rectangle.

```
//clear any existing drawings
g.clear();
```

Set the current drawing position to  the top-left corner of the rectangle, which is  0, 0

```
g.moveTo(rc.left,rc.top);

//start filling with the color specified by `fill`
g.beginFill(fill);
```

Draw a line to top-right corner of the rectangle from the current location (which is top-left corner). The `lineTo` method updates the current location so that subsequent drawings start from the new point.

```
g.lineTo(rc.right,rc.top);
```

Draw the remaining sides of the rectangle:

```
g.lineTo(rc.right,rc.bottom);
g.lineTo(rc.left,rc.bottom);
g.lineTo(rc.left,rc.top);

//end the fill.
g.endFill();
```

Check out the [livedocs page for `Graphics` class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Graphics.html#methodSummary) for more info.

---

All the visual components in Flex inherit directly/indirectly from the `UIComponent` class. The [updateDisplayList](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#updateDisplayList%28%29) method of `UIComponent` draws the object and/or sizes and positions its children. This is an advanced method that you might override when creating a subclass of `UIComponent`. When you override it in your child class, you should call `super.updateDisplayList` with the correct parameters to make sure that the base class components are properly updated.

Comment: Thanks Amarghosh and grapefrukt, i am adding some more thing. before all these code, it is calling 

super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

in the method. What will this actually do?

Answer (score 1):

That code is drawing a rectangle, albeit in a bit of a roundabout way.
The drawing api in flash uses a "draw head". I can't see any reason for using `g` instead of `graphics` other than to save some typing. `g.clear()` erases anything that has been drawn before. 
`g.moveTo(rc.left, rc.top)` moves that into position, in this case the top left corner of the rectangle (0,0). `g.beginFill(fill)` starts a fill, nothing surprising there. 
The `g.lineTo(x, y)` calls move the draw head around to the the four corners of the rectangle and finally `g.endFill()` completes the fill.

You can get the same result doing this:

```
graphics.clear();
graphics.beginFill(fill);
graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width , height);
// this last call is only needed if you're going to draw even more, 
// if not you can omit that too
graphics.endFill();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Degrafa](http://www.degrafa.org) makes this kind of thing much easier.